# Keyboard shortcut to empty workspace/environment in RStudio

Tags: r, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio

I was looking into google for Rstudio keyboard shortcuts. But could not find any to empty environment/workspace. Is there any such shortcut?

Comment: I've been hunting for this one for a while too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in Rstudio version >0.99.878 you can customize shortcuts  with "Modify Keyboard Shortcuts..." under the "Tools" tab. There you can set the "clear workspace" option to a keyboard shortcut of your choice.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Fastest solution. Makes me wonder if Spyder can do the same...

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

This shortcut opens up menu and clears the workspace variables.

Answer (score 8):

Why should you have one?

I think, that it is enough to type `rm(list =ls())` in the console. And it is also more sure from accidentally typing  a shortcut and possibly loosing important work.

However, you have a shortcut to restart the R session which is Ctrl+Shift+F10 that detach the loaded packages without voiding the global environment.

Comment: because that is about 5 characters additional (more or less depending on the autosuggest level the user has selected) that I have to type in 5 or 10 times extra for many instances in a day. If I have to do this all the time when I am checking solutions crafted/tweaked/developed for I wish to get them done quickly, particularly if I am scrambling to answer an SO question. Additionally, the environment clearance wins you a *"are you sure?"* pop-up each time.